# Conditional display of CCK fields

Tags: 7, entities

I was wondering if there is any other way apart from coding (and, possibly, using the rules module) to make the showing of a field dependent on the existance of another field.
Say you have in a node, a video and a photo. You want to show only the video in teaser but if you have not provided a value for the video, then the video field should not be showing, and instead the photo field should be showing. 
If you have provided a video, then the photo field should not be showing.
Any ideas?

Comment: After lot of experimenting I found out that I cannot use a rule to perform this. Rules does not work with Media file selectors. Actually, the Rules condition returns "false" if the "Entity has field" is about such a field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solutions I know except coding it by yourself its [Content Templates](http://drupal.org/project/contemplate) module. This module allows you to change the template directly from you back office.

The advantage it's that you don't need to deploy your code if you need small change.

You've also [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) that seems promising, I never tried but the description sounds good for what you need.

Comment: Thanks. It's more close to what I am looking for. I've used Content Templates sometime back but I do not remember much. Can I use an 'if' construct or something?

Comment: Seems to be yes, or at list their use a kind of eval function that allows you use PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I wanted to update this because it could help someone.

I would try [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields), it does exactly that. Drupal 6 & 7 only.

Comment: It is indeed an old issue and I have move away from drupal since so I can neither confirm nor deny what you say. It has to be left to the rest of the community to decide.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement template (or possibly module) [preprocess](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess) to do the checks and assign the html snippet to be outputted to a variable then just output it like this `<?php print $mytag; ?>` in your `node--[type].tpl.php`

Comment: Thank you. That would do, but I was wondering about a non coding solution.